# git Visual Studio ignored folders and permission errors

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

How do you include all project files and folders in the git repository in VS 2019 including the references so if you have to clone the repository you don't get permission errors?

Comment: What have you tried so far and how is it not working?

Comment: I have tried to include the bin folder by right-clicking it in VS, but the references folder as no option. I am looking steps on how to create a git repository that can be cloned afterward without permission errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "permission errors"? Also, "references" is probably not a folder but just a "shortcut" in VS to add references to the project.

Comment: permission errors: I was getting an http error when trying to clone a test repository I created from Visual Studio 2019. I believe I did not include the hidden files into the repository but there are some folders like /bin that are automatically not included and I am not clear on why. You're right regarding "references".

Comment: Your problem seems to be something completely different from what you think. It sounds like you have configured GIT/credentials incorrectly. Please [edit] your question and include all information about the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Ok, I will recreate the issue and update once I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You always could get into file manager, locate VS 2019, and Copy + Paste it

Comment: Good point! Thank you. The only thing is that it won't track the changes moving forward with git since those folders are not included in VS.